# How do you make Amazon Cloud GIS Server accessible outside local environment?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have services in the cloud and want to access them from applications outside the cloud.
How do I set permissions to consume services outside of the cloud?

Also, what is the format or syntax used for referencing Amazon Cloud GIS Server?
So, when I try to add GIS Server what would type in?

Comment: is this a GIS specific AMI?

Comment: ESRI based or GIS in general?

Answer (score 1):

Have look on ESRI document on Amazon Cloud GIS setup.
  http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/estimating-cost-gis-cloud.pdf

In mean time, other opensource GIS server GeoServer also now available for Cloud as GeoSolutions recently announced. 
http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2011/03/geoserver-in-da-cloud.html

You could select GIS Server based on your needs and budget. Hope this helpful.

Comment: This is an ArcGIS Server esri. I'll check out the link and opensource option. I have an instance in the cloud, just need to acces it outside of the cloud. Does anyone have documentation for setting permissions and/or opening access to be consumed by outside applications???

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance can only allow network traffic from sources and ports defined in its **security group**. When you use Amazon EC2, you need to set up some security groups that correspond to the types of things you'll be doing with your EC2 instances. This topic describes some common security groups you can configure for different ArcGIS Server deployments.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#/Common_security_group_configurations/00rq00000020000000/

Note: Restarting an instance on EC2 will change the IP address.

Every time you stop and start the instance, Amazon assigns your instance a new machine name and Public DNS name/IP Address. To help you avoid having to manually edit the ArcGIS Server configuration files that store these changing values, the ArcGIS Server AMI has a service built in to it that updates the appropriate files when the instance starts.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#/Administering_your_Amazon_EC2_machine_with_Remote_Desktop/00rq0000000m000000/