# Integrate QGIS into Hadoop cloud is it possible?

Tags: qgis, hadoop

It might be very basic question.

Can I integrate QGIS +Hadoop cloud?

Currently I am going through [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42736/open-source-cloud-gis) and [few research articles](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Quantum_GIS_now_has_an_Opensource_Cloud_Hosting_Service_Publish_your_own_maps_directly_from_the_desktop_Publish_your_first_map_within_minutes_Its_free_to_get_started_http_wwwqgiscloudcom_pages_quicks) & researching on my side.

In upcoming ArcGIS 10.2 ESRI announced that there will be cloud extension in ArcGIS. So similarly can I integrate open source desktop gis (like QGIS) with hadoop cloud?

**Purpose :**  Analyze the social networking  trend.

Any help/suggestion will be great !!

thanks in advance : )

Comment: See also [GIS Tools for Hadoop for QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167177/gis-tools-for-hadoop-for-qgis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other options that you could use for doing large scale cloud processing. I would suggest you take a look at [Geotrellis](http://www.azavea.com/products/geotrellis/) from Azavea. It has a strong code base and builds on several other products to support scaling and distribution.

Comment: I will look into it and let you know..thanks for your reply : )