# GIS Tools for Hadoop for QGIS

Tags: qgis, hadoop

I am wondering if something like this: http://esri.github.io/gis-tools-for-hadoop/ exists but for QGIS. Or if these tools be adapted for QGIS.

Comment: What about Spatial Hadoop? http://spatialhadoop.cs.umn.edu/ Do your spatial analysis right in the database just like PostGIS, etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GIS Tools for Hadoop read from and write to several standard and documented formats, including CSV, WKT, WKB, Esri GeoServices REST JSON, and GeoJSON.  So with some effort it should be possible to use the GIS Tools for Hadoop with QGIS.  In fact, there is [indirect evidence that such has been done](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/52).

As far as integration like the [Geoprocessing Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/geoprocessing-tools-for-hadoop), such integration with QGIS would be a nice opportunity for a [community contribution](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop#contributing).

[Disclosure: I am a collaborator on the Esri GIS Tools for Hadoop.]